# PhpMyadmin error #1064

Tags: php, mysql

okay so i have transferred my website % database over from an old computer which had now died and am trying to set it up on my own mac locally however I am running into a few issues. As of now i have setup xampp and phpmyadmin however when i try to import my `.sql` database.

I am getting an error:

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 AUTO_INCREMENT=3' at line 31

-- version 2.8.0.1

### -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net

-- Host: custsql-ipg68.eigbox.net
-- Generation Time: Aug 22, 2015 at 05:57 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.44

### -- PHP Version: 4.4.9

### -- Database: `blake`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `doctor`

```
CREATE TABLE `doctor` (
  `D_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `D_name` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `D_SSn` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `Age` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `office` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`D_id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `doctor`

```
INSERT INTO `doctor` VALUES (1, 'David Jones', '123-64-2654', '48', '134-264-4567', '1234 st boulevard', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', '12345', '123456789');
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `patient`

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `P_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `P_Name` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `P_SSn` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `BirthDate` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `P_Lname` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(85) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`P_id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `patient`

```
INSERT INTO `patient` VALUES (1, 'Mark', '624-54-1326', 'March-16-1856', '4172696000', '3801 South National Avenue', 'Springfield', 'MO', '65807', 'Alan', 'Male', 'test@domainname.com');
INSERT INTO `patient` VALUES (4, 'Blake', '00012', '01/09/2015', '093284203894', '66 evergreen street', 'sydey', 'qld', '4007', 'douglas', 'male', 'test@gmail.com.au');
```

Comment: should be `... ENGINE=INNODB, AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare table type you should use `ENGINE` instead of `TYPE`. `Type` is wrong syntax.

Change from

```
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
) TYPE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

To

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```